# Invalid type in Gauss-Seidel Function

Tags: c++

I'm making a function that will use Gauss Seidel Method to solve A*x=b. When I run the function I get the following error messages:

main.cpp:28:40: error: invalid types 'double[int]' for array subscript

sum[i] = ( 1/A[i][j] ) * x[j] ) ;

---------------------^ (tiny arrow pointing to here)

main.cpp:31:32: error: invalid types 'double[int]' for array subscript

x[i] = ( 1 / A[i][i] ) * ( b[i] - sum[i] ) ;

-------------------^ (tiny arrow pointing to here)

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void Gauss(int n, double * A, double * b, double * x) 
{
    double sum[20];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++)
    {
        sum[i] = 0;
    }


    for (int iter = 0 ; iter < n ; iter++)    
    {

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++ ) 
        {

            for ( int j = 0; j < 20 ; j++ ) 
            {
                if ( i != j )
                    sum[i] = ( 1/A[i][j] ) * x[j] ) ;
            }

            x[i] = ( 1 / A[i][i] ) * ( b[i] - sum[i] ) ;
        }

    }

    return;
}


int main() 
{
    //defining matrix A
    double A[20][20];    
    //defining vectors x and b
    double x[20];        
    double b[20];
    int i;

    //for Matrix A

    for (i = 0 ; i<20 ; ++i)
    {
        A[i][i]= 2.0; 
        A[i][i+1] = -1.0; 
        A[i+1][i] = -1.0; 
    }

    //for vector x
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 20 ; ++i)
    {
        x[i]=0;
    }

    //for vector b
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1 || i == 19)
            b[i]=1.0;
        else
            b[i]=0;
    }           


    return 0; 
}
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Is the `A` array one dimension or two?

Comment: Since you tagged this as C++, you should be using `std::vector` and not arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to pass a 2D array to a function that takes a `double*`, but 2D arrays **do not decay** to pointers (not even to pointer to pointers). The correct way is to have a `double (*A) [20]` as a parameter, i.e. pointer-to-array-20-of-doubles.